# How to get annotation value from AnnotationDescription.Loadable in Bytebuddy

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I want get annotation value form a specific annotation, such as @Callcount, which has a field named key.

```
 MethodList<MethodDescription.InDefinedShape> methods = typeDefinition.getDeclaredMethods();
    for (MethodDescription.InDefinedShape method : methods) {
        AnnotationDescription.Loadable<CalledCount> callCountAnno;
        if ((callCountAnno = method.getDeclaredAnnotations().ofType(CalledCount.class)) != null) {
           callCountAnno.getValue(?);//how can i do here?
        }
    }
```

i don't know how to build the parameter of method callCountAnno.getValue(), what i shoud do?

Comment: No experience with this so I don't feel comfortable making an answer right off the bat. I just skimmed through the javadocs for Byte Buddy and it looks like the parameter type needs to be `MethodDescription.InDefinedShape`. So try `getValue(method)`

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution would be to load the annotation which allows you to access the value in a type-safe manner. You can do so via the `load` or `loadSilent` methods. Alternatively, you need to provide the propery you want to resolve. You can provide a loaded method reference via: `MethodDescription.ForLoadedMethod( ... )`.